# Possible to access 'root' model in underscore template?

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, for-in-loop

In underscore normally when an object is passed in as the model, the properties will be directly accessible within the template.

**MODEL**

```
var obj {
   prop1: 'a',
   prop2: 'b'
}
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<p>Property 1 = <%= prop1 %></p>
<p>Property 2 = <%= prop2 %></p>
```

But is it possible to access `obj`? This may seem unnecessary but in my case I want to run a `for in` loop on the object in my template, but I can't do this if I have no access to the model.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, the context object you pass in will be exposed as a variable called `obj`

```js
var dataForView = {
   prop1: 'a',
   prop2: 'b'
}

var template = templateForData.innerHTML;
target.innerHTML = _.template(template , dataForView);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id='templateForData'>
<p>Property 1 = <%= prop1 %></p>
<p>Property 2 = <%= prop2 %></p>
<p><%= console.log(obj) %> </p>
</script>
<!-- Create your target -->
<div id="target"></div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3dtbscr6/)

Although I believe the ability to pass an object as the context [has been deprecated as of version 1.7](http://underscorejs.org/#1.7.0) so it should be done like this if not already.

```js
var dataForView = {
   prop1: 'a',
   prop2: 'b'
}

var template = templateForData.innerHTML;
var compiled = _.template(template)(dataForView);
target.innerHTML = compiled;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id='templateForData'>
<p>Property 1 = <%= prop1 %></p>
<p>Property 2 = <%= prop2 %></p>
<p><%= console.log(obj) %> </p>
</script>
<!-- Create your target -->
<div id="target"></div>
```